# 'this' context in browserify modules

Tags: javascript, browserify

In a simple `browserify` app, I'd like to use the `this` keyword to reference other functions in an exported object, but it doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect it to:

```js
(function() {
  module.exports = {
    a: function() {
      console.log('Hello World');
    },
    b: function() {
      this.a(); // Problem: this is set to window.document
    }
  };
})();
```

I'd assumed that the above code would work, but it seems that `this` is set to `window.document` instead of the exported object. I'm fairly sure I've had this working in the past, so it's probably something simple, but I'm a bit stuck on it!

I'm aware that I could export the object itself to `window`, or else make it a named variable that can be referenced, but I'd like to understand why the above code doesn't work.

Many thanks!

Comment: are you sure it's `window.document` ? how do you call `b` ?

Comment: How are you calling function b?

Comment: I'm including this module in another script, then calling it:

    `var module = require('module.js'); module.b();`

Comment: Ah! Actually, I wasn't doing that at all, I was binding the function call to `document.ready`, which is why this wasn't working as expected! Thanks @dustmouse @dandavis you helped me track it down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set "this" to object you need to invoke this function as object property, like

`foo.a()`

or use call/apply to explicitly set "this"

`bar.a.apply(foo,[args])`

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much it - turns out that I was instantiating the function by binding it to `document.ready` instead of calling it like `foo.a()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  Change your code to below and it works.

```
(function () {
   var module = new Object();
   module.exports = {
        a : function () {
            console.log('Hello World');
        },
        b : function () {
            this.a();
        }
   };
   module.exports.b();
})();
```